# Passing object from Javascript to PHP using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, object

**Object:**

```
var obj = [{id: 1, name: "Peter", lastname: "Griffin"}]
```

**Javascript:**

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'post',
    url:'http://api/test.php',
    data: {     
        func: "addtodatabase",
        objectToBePassed: obj   //also tried JSON.stringify(obj)
    },          
    success: function(data) {
       //code here
    }
});
```

**PHP:**

```
$data = json_decode($_REQUEST['objectToBePassed'], true);
```

I can't seem to make it work. Help?

Comment: Have you inspected the value of `$_REQUEST['objectToBePassed']` as you got it? And the value of `$data` after the decode? Your question lacks information about what goes wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you seem to be confused on this. You do not need to `json_decode()` that. Once its in the post body. Just access it as it is:

```
$data = $_POST['objectToBePassed'];
```

[**Here is a demo**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/KYSPBA)